# How to use the where clause in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to query my EF Code First database so it will return all bookings that where made by the currently logged in user. I'm not quite getting the syntax correct somewhere, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the correct direction.

The two different ways I've tried to achieve this:

```cs
List<Booking> bookings = new List<Booking>();
string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
foreach(var b in db.Bookings.Where(b => b.Customer.Id == userid))
{
    bookings.Add(b);
}
```

```cs
string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Customer).Include(b => b.Invoice).Include(b => b.Payment).Include(b => b.Vehicle).Where(b => b.Customer.Id == userid);
return View(bookings.ToList());
```

None of these ways have returned any of the bookings in the database, so I'm sure my logic is wrong here somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the first one you are not including Customer in your query. So b.Customer will always be null. For the other one you might have wrong relations. Are you sure that customer have at least invoice, payment and vehicle? What is the result of this? var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Customer).Where(b => b.Customer.Id == userid).ToList();

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query, you forgot to include Customer navigation property, so the customer always fails and no bookings will return.

Although in your 2nd query, you have included customer, invoice and etc! In that case, only returns customers if they have a booking which their booking got an invoice, payment and etc.

This query should work with you:

```
string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var bookings = db.Bookings
                 .Include(b => b.Customer)
                 .Where(b => b.Customer.Id == userid)
                 .ToList();

return View(bookings);
```

It seems you are using EF with EagerMode enabled, so you need to `Include` customer or any related fields in your where criteria.

**My off-topic recommendation:**

Please don't return entities that fetched directly from ORM. First, convert them into a [DTO (with AutoMapper or any other object mappers)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).